# Who is this fifth turtle?

Tags: character-identification, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

In an advertisement for a TMNT comic titled *From the Ashes*, there is a picture of the four turtles I'm familiar with, plus a fifth one wearing a yellow mask and armed with a gauntlet from which four blades emerge - does anyone recognize this new character?

[image: The cover of "Teenage Mutant Turtles: From the Ashes" issue #01]

Answer (score 34):

#### [Jennika](https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/Jennika_(IDW))

> Jennika, also known as Jenny or Jenn for short, was the ninja chūnin of Splinter's Foot Clan, a dear friend to the Turtles and for a time was a love interest to Casey Jones. Originally human, she is now a mutant turtle after her life was saved by an emergency transfusion of mutagenic blood donated by Leonardo due to her loss of blood.